# debug-apk work fine but sign apk release crash on main acitvity

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, apk

Debug apk run fine but release signed apk crash on main activity. I have  checked everything but I don't know where is the problem.[build.gradle][1]

```
   android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.newtrendsdeveloper.unorthodox"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 51
            versionName "4.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            debug {}
        }

    flavorDimensions "color"
    productFlavors {
        blue {}
        green {
            applicationIdSuffix ".test"
            versionNameSuffix "\"4.0-Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.407]\n" +
                    "      (c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.\n" +
                    "      \n" +
                    "      C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\Tusky-master\\Tusky-master\\app>\";" + getGitSha()
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}

ext.supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0'
ext.daggerVersion = '2.19'
```

// If libraries are changed here, they should also be changed in the **LicenseActivity**

```
dependencies {
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.`enter code here`9@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
```

Comment: share crash log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably it's the minifyEnabled true in your gradle file.

This removes unused code and obfuscates the code. So you can check what is the crash log, probably it's a class not found or null pointer exception. Check what is missing, and then in the build output you can search for a file called usage.txt. This includes all the things that were removed, and you can make sure it is being removed. If it is, then modify the proguard rules to keep that class.

You can check the documentation to understand more about proguard:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Of course another way to check if this is the issue is just to change the minifyEnabled to false and try again. If that works, then you can turn it back on and figure out what is causing the problem.

Comment: Extra: Add "-printusage <output-dir>/usage.txt" to your proguard, and you will get a usage.txt when you build your release app. This file will have all the names of the class which is "removed" by proguard. If the class in crash log can be found in this file, you have to "keep" it in your proguard.